# Verify unique ID number before writing a new number in PIC18F

Tags: embedded, pic, firmware

Each chip should be unique by number, so I want to prevent that a chip would be burned twice. It's a gap in the order.. Each number should be used.

I have searched the internet and found out how to write unique numbers on specific place called "User ID".

Therefore I have got two files:
-"Myprogram.hex"
-"MyUniqueNumber_SQTP.num"

I use MPLAB X v3.35 and the IPE version for writing.

Does any one know if there is a program that verify a "User ID" (which is common) before writing the microchip. For example.. blank check

I know that the IPE will generate a combined hex file for that "one" chip. That is possible because the unique number is on address(hex): 200000-200007
The main program doesn't use this address.

Comment: If you know the exact format of the binary image, then you can implement a script (e.g., in Python) which injects the ID into the hex file, at that specific address, before burning the image to flash. BTW, in order to make sure that this address is never in use (i.e., reserve it for your specific purpose), you should probably add an appropriate rule in your linker settings.

Comment: Thanks barak manos, but combined hex is not the problem. I want to verify if there is firmware in the chip and if there is a number before writing a new one.

Comment: Read out the chip (or at least enough of it to satisfy yourself) and see what you get.  Of course if you program an anti-readback fuse you won't be able to do that.  Perhaps you need to solve this problem by establishing clear work procedures and record keeping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PICKIT 3, which supports SQTP, you can probably use its command line interface (pk3cmd.exe, bundled with the MPLAP IDE). You can first read either the the *ID Memory* (using -GI) or a portion of memory (using -GP) to a file and then verify whether it's already burnt. It would be easy then to integrate this to a JAVA/.Net application to automate the process.

For other debuggers there should be similar CLI.

[PK3CMD command line options](http://lars.mec.ua.pt/public/LAR%20Projects/Humanoid/2011_WilliamLage/Guias%20e%20Tutoriais/MPLAB_IDE_8_56_Release_Notes/Readme%20for%20PK3CMD.txt)